# Networking Tag Clarification

Tags: support, tags, tag-wikis

The tag [networking](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) has no current definition nor usage guidance, yet has three questions in it. It appears the one of the questions was attempting to use the [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) tag, and that some questions in the [internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) tag were actually looking for what I thought [networking](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) was all about.

Can we have a wiki/description for the [networking](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) tag?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a start:

---

Challenges related to topics in [Computer Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_network), including:

- [TCP/IP Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) (including [lower layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_layer) - Ethernet, WiFi, PPP, etc)
- [IP/IPV6 addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address)
- [Routing protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_protocol) and associated calculations
- [NIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller), [router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)) and [switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch) configuration